# creating dialogflow v2 project with serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, dialogflow-es, serverless-framework

Having issues trying to run a new AWS/Serverless/Dialogflow project.  I am sure it is something simple that I am just not seeing.

### Steps

- Created initial project using: `serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript`
- moved *handler.js* to *src/* & updated *serverless.yml*
- npm installed `actions-on-google`
- followed the [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) example and updated *src/handler.js*

  ```
  import { dialogflow, Image } from 'actions-on-google';

  const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

  app.intent("test.intent", (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Hi, how is it going?");
    conv.ask("Here is a picture of a cat!");
    conv.ask(new Image({
      url: "https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg",
      alt: "A fluffy cat!"
    }));
  });

  exports.fulfillment = app;
  ```
- also updated *tsconfig.json* to match another Typescript project

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "allowJs": true,
      "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
    ]
  }
  ```

For thoroughness here is my *serverless.yml*.  (I manually created the API Gateway because serverless creates the lambda-proxy and I haven't looked into the other config.)

```
service:
  name: test-lambda

# Add the serverless-webpack plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

functions:
  fulfillment:
    handler: src/handler.fulfillment
    # events:
    #   - http:
    #       method: get
    #       path: hello
```

### Error

The project compiles and deploys successfully but when the lambda is called I keep getting

`(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

P.S. the example source chose to use a cat!

Comment: I don't think you can just set your handler to an express app without a little [additional plumbing](https://gist.github.com/marcorei/cd9c9b2e5682718c897df31354cd6f9f#file-handler-ts).  Have you already [read this](https://medium.com/@marcorei/developing-for-the-google-assistant-using-typescript-and-amazon-web-services-e7c81df9a436)?

Comment: @Mike Patrick Thanks but that info is for Dialogflow V1 which requires a Request/Response to be passed into the library.  Ultimately, I will be migrating my V1 project to V2 just need to figure this bit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had some time to circle back to this problem and came across this [git issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/173).

Essentially the `dialogflow` instance needed to be encapsulated by the lambda.

```
exports.fulfillment = function(event, context, callback) {
  app.handler(event, {})
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status != 200) {
        callback(null, {
          "fulfillmentText": `I got status code: ${res.status}`
        });
      } else {
        callback(null, res.body);
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      callback(null, {
        "fulfillmentText": `There was an error\n${e}`
      });
    });
};
```