# Google Actions Smart Home on Lambda not working

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been trying to get my Google Actions Smart Home (nodejs) working in AWS lambda. However it isn't working. Whenever I connect it on the Google Home app, I just get a message of "Couldn't update the setting...". I've already configured the API gateway correctly and set the Handler to "index.smarthome" as shown in the below image link. **Why isn't it working, and how can I get my lambda google  action smart home working?**

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvSaO.png)

My firebase version is working though (modified from the washing machine example at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#2).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {smarthome} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = smarthome();

app.onSync(body => {
  return {
    requestId: 'ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf',
    payload: {
      agentUserId: '123',
      devices: [{
        id: 'washer',
        type: 'action.devices.types.WASHER',
        traits: [
          'action.devices.traits.OnOff',
          'action.devices.traits.StartStop',
          'action.devices.traits.RunCycle',
          'action.devices.traits.Modes',
          'action.devices.traits.Toggles',
        ],
        name: {
          defaultNames: ['My Washer'],
          name: 'Washer',
          nicknames: ['Washer']
        },
        deviceInfo: {
          manufacturer: 'Acme Co',
          model: 'acme-washer',
          hwVersion: '1.0',
          swVersion: '1.0.1'
        },
        attributes: {
          pausable: true,
          availableModes: [{
              name: 'load',
              name_values: [{
                  name_synonym: ['load'],
                  lang: 'en'
                }],
              settings: [{
                  setting_name: 'small',
                  setting_values: [{
                      setting_synonym: ['small'],
                      lang: 'en'
                    }]
                  }, {
                  setting_name: 'large',
                  setting_values: [{
                      setting_synonym: ['large'],
                      lang: 'en'
                    }]
                }],
              ordered: true
            }],
          availableToggles: [{
              name: 'Turbo',
              name_values: [{
                  name_synonym: ['turbo'],
                  lang: 'en'
              }]
          }]
        }
    }]
    }
  };
});

app.onExecute((body) => {
  const {requestId} = body;
  const payload = {
    commands: [{
      ids: [],
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      states: {
        online: true,
      },
    }],
  };
  for (const input of body.inputs) {
    for (const command of input.payload.commands) {
      for (const device of command.devices) {
        const deviceId = device.id;
        payload.commands[0].ids.push(deviceId);
        for (const execution of command.execution) {
          const execCommand = execution.command;
          const {params} = execution;
          switch (execCommand) {
            case 'action.devices.commands.OnOff':
              payload.commands[0].states.on = params.on;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.StartStop':
              payload.commands[0].states.isRunning = params.start;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.PauseUnpause':
              payload.commands[0].states.isPaused = params.pause;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.SetModes':
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.SetToggles':
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    requestId: requestId,
    payload: payload,
  };
});

exports.smarthome = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

---

And here is the code that I used in my AWS lambda function. I referenced https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs & [creating dialogflow v2 project with serverless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865741/creating-dialogflow-v2-project-with-serverless) to make it lambda compatible. **The main difference between the lambda and firebase versions is the "exports.smarthome" code.**

---

```
const {smarthome} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = smarthome();

app.onSync(body => {
  return {
    requestId: 'ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf',
    payload: {
      agentUserId: '123',
      devices: [{
        id: 'washer',
        type: 'action.devices.types.WASHER',
        traits: [
          'action.devices.traits.OnOff',
          'action.devices.traits.StartStop',
          'action.devices.traits.RunCycle',
          'action.devices.traits.Modes',
          'action.devices.traits.Toggles',
        ],
        name: {
          defaultNames: ['My Washer'],
          name: 'Washer',
          nicknames: ['Washer']
        },
        deviceInfo: {
          manufacturer: 'Acme Co',
          model: 'acme-washer',
          hwVersion: '1.0',
          swVersion: '1.0.1'
        },
        attributes: {
          pausable: true,
          availableModes: [{
              name: 'load',
              name_values: [{
                  name_synonym: ['load'],
                  lang: 'en'
                }],
              settings: [{
                  setting_name: 'small',
                  setting_values: [{
                      setting_synonym: ['small'],
                      lang: 'en'
                    }]
                  }, {
                  setting_name: 'large',
                  setting_values: [{
                      setting_synonym: ['large'],
                      lang: 'en'
                    }]
                }],
              ordered: true
            }],
          availableToggles: [{
              name: 'Turbo',
              name_values: [{
                  name_synonym: ['turbo'],
                  lang: 'en'
              }]
          }]
        }
    }]
    }
  };
});

app.onExecute((body) => {
  const {requestId} = body;
  const payload = {
    commands: [{
      ids: [],
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      states: {
        online: true,
      },
    }],
  };
  for (const input of body.inputs) {
    for (const command of input.payload.commands) {
      for (const device of command.devices) {
        const deviceId = device.id;
        payload.commands[0].ids.push(deviceId);
        for (const execution of command.execution) {
          const execCommand = execution.command;
          const {params} = execution;
          switch (execCommand) {
            case 'action.devices.commands.OnOff':
              payload.commands[0].states.on = params.on;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.StartStop':
              payload.commands[0].states.isRunning = params.start;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.PauseUnpause':
              payload.commands[0].states.isPaused = params.pause;
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.SetModes':
              break;
            case 'action.devices.commands.SetToggles':
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    requestId: requestId,
    payload: payload,
  };
});

exports.smarthome = function(event, context, callback) {
  app.handler(event, {})
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status != 200) {
        callback(null, {
          "fulfillmentText": `I got status code: ${res.status}`
        });
      } else {
        callback(null, res.body);
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      callback(null, {
        "fulfillmentText": `There was an error\n${e}`
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Is it an authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your AWS CloudWatch logs and see what happens when the lambda is called.  You can print to stdout in your lambda and have it show up in these logs.

Comment: Ack, that was supposed to be comment, not an answer.  But of course, I don't have enough points to comment.  So bogus answers are the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Along with your Cloudwatch logs, you could also have a look at your Stackdriver logs.